# 301 re-direct OLD home-page to specfic page, all else to NEW homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm moving my site to a new domain where the content from the HOMEPAGE on the OLD domain now lives on a specific page on the NEW domain. My question is- how do i re-direct the OLD homepage to this specific page on the new domain, and then send every other request from the old domain to the homepage of the NEW domain. I know thats kind of confusing- here's an example. Working with apache so will most likely do this in the htaccess file of the old domain.

I need

old.com -> new.com/specific-page

everything else -> new.com

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by using mod_rewrite on the old domain. Put the following directives in a .htaccess file in the www-root.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://new.com/specific-page [R,L]
RewriteRule ^ http://new.com [R,L]
```

The first rule will only match when the url-path is empty (that is, if you request `http://old.com/`). Any url that is not matched by the first rule will be matched by the second rule and redirected that way.

When both rules work as expected, change the `R` flag to `R=301` (so that it says `[R=301,L]`). This makes the redirect permanent.